# Google My Business API fails

Tags: google-my-business-api

Getting a strange error message and there is literally nothing on it anywhere I look. Granted access to Google My Business API, followed directions here;

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/get-started

All went well, but the expected 200 response was actually the below;

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", 
    "message": "The request was blocked. Quota configuration not found for the requesting project.", 
    "code": 403, 
    "details": [
      {
        "violations": [
          {
            "description": "The request was blocked. Quota configuration not found for the requesting project.", 
            "subject": "project:XXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        ], 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to add quotas in Google Developer console, or, alternately, if this message is a result of expired permissions perhaps? (Granted access in Feb, did not use until now?)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get when the project in question does not have Google My Business API access, as granted through their official process etc. When I used the correct project I got a 200 and all is well.

So sayeth the GMB folks themselves, who answered my email same day!